# Calling a class method on itself

Tags: c++, class

I am not sure what I am attempting to do is possible however there might be a trick to make it work. I am trying to call a recursive function from within a class function and I do not know how to set the first argument to the class. For example:

```
Class A{
public:
   A();
   ~A();

   void B();
}

void A::B(){
   C( ****This is where I am unsure);
}

void C(A name){

}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You should also probably change it to take a reference, depending on what you want to do with `name`

Comment: Karthik, would this be changing the call in function B() to C(this) and then changing function C to void C(A *name){...}?

Comment: No I mean following the other answers listed and changing C to `void C(A& name)` What you are talking about is C pointers, and that is different from [C++ references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you want to pass copy of the current object to the method, so:

```
C(*this);
```

`this` is a special pointer which gets implicitly passed to every member function and points to the object itself. So you just need to dereference `this`.

Comment: Note that, in this case, it makes a copy of the instance because `C` takes its parameter by value.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It does, that is what the interface asks for, that is what it gets. Anyways, I modified to reflect better.

Comment: Is there any impact if it only passes ref parameter `C(this)`?

Comment: @lwinhtooko: Passing a reference will change the current object, passing by value will change a copy of the object which gets passed to `C`. So it depends on do u want to change a copy of the object inside method `C` or do you want to change the original object inside `C`?

Comment: @Alok Save If I just want to read the object's attributes or use the functions of the object, should I use ref parameter? If I use passing parameter by value, I think the new copied object will be created and saved in heap. Will that value be delete after the function is called?

Comment: @lwinhtooko: When you pass by value a new object will be created(*though not on heap*), Any methods you call on this object will not change the state of the original object(*since it it just a copy*).So question boils down to do you want to modify state of original object or copied object? My guess is the former. Also, note the copy of the object is created by calling the copy constructor.